# What is the use case for mutex_type specified in `unique_lock`, `scoped_lock` and `lock_guard`?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

The c++11 mutex RAII types for guarding `std::mutex` all have a typedef:

```
typedef Mutex mutex_type;
```

- [`std::lock_guard::mutex_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)
- [`std::unique_lock::mutex_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock)
- [`std::scoped_lock::mutex_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock)

What is the point of this member typedef? At first I thought it could be used to generalize creating an object for moving the lock (in the case of the `unique_lock`) for example:

```
template<SomeLock>
void function(SomeLock in)
    SomeLock::mutex_type newMutex;
    //Do something
```

But I cannot imagine a use for this.

A further note is that it doesn't appear to be used anywhere in the implementation of the `locks` (at least not in VisualC++).

**What is a use case of the member `mutex_type`?**

Comment: *"But the actual implementation would require template parameters so you know the type at compile time anyway."* - That's only true if you template on `Mutex`, but you're likely to template on `Lock` so you need `Lock::mutex_type`.

Comment: @Holt, Yeah i was just realizing that. But it still isnt clear what you would do with the `mutex_type` in `function`. I guess it could be a class template and allows you to tell the class which type of lock and mutex to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a type alias for each template parameter is normal in the standard library. Off hand, I can't recall a template in `std` that *doesn't* alias all it's template parameters as member types

Having a distinct name for a type alias in a group of related classes allows for that group to be easily distinguished from other classes, e.g. for SFINAE

```
template<typename Lock, typename = std::void_t<Lock::mutex_type>>
void usesLock(Lock lock); // Substitution failure for most instantiations of Lock
```

It also allows you to easily specify a parameter of appropriate type.

```
template<typename Lock>
void usesMutex(Lock::mutex_type & mut);
```

Comment: So, I like the path of your answer, but can you clarify. In 2, why would you need to use `Lock::mutex_type` when the use of the `mut` (ie. by calling `lock` ) would guarantee that the implemented type meets the concept required. I guess this would let you be more specific that the `Lock` must define `mutex_type` which means its more likely to be a `std` synchro type. But I can still implement a class with a typedef of `mutex_type` and use this function (in both examples). I am still not sure exactly what this would gain for me?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox You *don't need to*. But I find it clearer.